# Implementing help page in Asp.Net website

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to implement help pages for a website something similar to http://help.smartertools.com/SmarterMail/v8/Default.aspx?p=_SA&v=8.2.4212&lang=en-US&page=systemadmin%2ffrmdomains . Is there any open source or paid component to achieve this in Asp.Net.

I searched in the google but could only find tools for generating knowledge bases and forums.

Thanks